# HTTP Error 403 When Trying to Login

Tags: plugins, login, errors

I'm currently trying to log into a WordPress website, which I downloaded off the virtual server, now in my local server (MAMP, because I'm on a Mac machine). When I try and log into the backend, it successfully gives me the WordPress login screen. After I log in with the correct credentials, it gives me the following:

> Error 403
>
> We're sorry, but we could not fulfill your request for /wp-login.php on this server.
>
> You do not have permission to access this server. Data may not be posted from offsite forms.
>
> Your technical support key is: *key number*
>
> You can use this key to fix this problem yourself.
>
> If you are unable to fix the problem yourself, please contact wiley at illinimedia.com and be sure to provide the technical support key shown above.

One of the plugins we use on this site is Bad Behavior, which I believe is the cause of the problem. So, I looked up different support posts, such as:

- [this one](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-403-)
- [and this one](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-access-admin-but-error-message-locks-me-out?replies=2)

I've tried removing the bad behavior folder out of the plugin folder, "deactivating" the plugin. Then, I restarted my Apache server. But no luck.

Is there something else that I could be trying?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you did not correctly [move WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) and your local install is trying to login to the hosted site. I am guessing that this is the problem becasue of this sentence, "Data may not be posted from offsite forms." Your login form should not really ever be "offsite". You need to [change the site URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) just as if you've moved the site from one domain name to another.

If it isn't multisite, you can edit `wp-config.php` like this:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

"http://example.com" in your case will be something like "http://localhost/yoursite" or an IP like "http://192.168.1.2/yoursite". The IP is better because it will allow the site to work for any computer on the local network. You may also need a port number after the domain, like "http://192.168.1.2:8080". You will have to use the actual values for your local server. MAMP should be able to tell you what those need to be.